# MATLAB output to PHP code

Tags: php, matlab, passthru

I want to pass MATLAB output to my php code.

My MATLAB code, I have:

```
function x = returnX()
    x = 100;
end
```

And my PHP code:

```
<?php
     $command = "matlab -nojvm -nodesktop -nodisplay -r \"x = returnX();\"";
     passthru($command, $output);
     echo($output)
?>
```

However, this prints 0, not 100.
When I type the command in my cmd, it shows 100. But when I try it through PHP code, it does not work. Can anyone help me how to set the output value of MATLAB to php variable? Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/passthru says the second parameter of passthru is for the return status, not the output. If the command succeeded, you'd be expecting a return status of zero, so that is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You should rather use `exec`, which return the standard output, rather than the exit code like `passthru`.

display the output in the matlab code:

```
function x = returnX()
    x = 100;
    display(x);
end
```

use `exec` in the php code:

```
<?php
     $command = "matlab -nojvm -nodesktop -nodisplay -r \"x = returnX();\"";
     $output=exec($command);
     echo($output)
?>
```

Comment: Note that `exec` will only return the last line of output, which is probably fine in this case.

Comment: Its showing nothing on the page, and on `var_dump($output)` its showing `string '' (length=0)` as a result.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php):

> If the return_var argument is present, the return status of the Unix
>   command will be placed here.

You are `echo`ing the return value from the Matlab command, not standard output.  Since the command executed correctly, a 0 is returned.  `passthru()` will send the content from standard output "without any interference" to the client.

Also, make sure your hosting provider allows you to make system calls from within a PHP script.  Many hosts disable executing server-side commands for security reasons.  Check out the support of safe mode and `disabled_functions` in your `php.ini`.